# OR operator in extendscript

Tags: javascript, operators, extendscript

I'm creating some scripts voor InDesign to speed up the process.
I have created a script where a certain line, I think, should work but InDesign disagrees.

It fails on `("Geen"||"None");` in the following
`app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedCharacterStyle = myDoc.characterStyles.item("[Geen]"||"[None]");`

I expect it to change to a characterStyle `[Geen]` or `[None]`. Depending on what is available in the predefined character styles.

What am I doing wrong? This seems kinda basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately is not that easy. If you use `doc.characterStyles.item('foo')` it still will give you an `[object CharacterStyle]`. Even tough it does not exsist.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
$.writeln(doc.characterStyles.item('foo'));
// writes [object CharacterStyle] into the console
```

What you can do is use a `try{}catch(error){}` block and ask for the `name` property of that object. In that case InDesign will throw an error that you can catch. Then you can fall back to the default character style [None]

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
try{
  $.writeln(doc.characterStyles.item('foo').name);
}catch(e) {
  $.writeln(e);
  $.writeln(doc.characterStyles.item('[None]').name);
}
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by mdomino. You can use the `isValid` property.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

if(doc.characterStyles.item('foo').isValid === true) {
  $.writeln('doc.characterStyles.item(\'foo\') exists');
} else {
  $.writeln('use doc.characterStyles.item(\'[None]\') because ');
  var defaultStyle = doc.characterStyles.item('[None]');
  $.writeln(defaultStyle.name + ' is ' + defaultStyle.isValid);
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want to avoid a `try catch`, you can alternatively check the property `doc.characterStlyes.item("[Geen]").isValid`.